# Responsive web design is working on desktop but not on mobile device

Tags: mobile, responsive-design

I have a website which must be responsive for mobile phones. I've created it using my desktop. When I adjust browser windows it's working perfectly for mobile phone but when I check it on my real mobile phone: Samsung Galaxy S2 it's not responsive to the mobile view.

What could be the wrong?

Comment: You're going to have to add more info and code for anyone to be helpful. Your CSS, HTML, etc. What framework (such as Twitter Bootstrap) you're using, if any, etc.

Comment: Here's a quick way to check your device's current (virtual) viewport settings: https://whatismyviewport.com/

Answer (score 351, accepted):

You are probably missing the [viewport meta tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag) in the html head:

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Without it the device assumes and sets the viewport to full size.

More info [here](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/quick-tip-dont-forget-the-viewport-meta-tag/).

Comment: It can work on browser without this line but on mobile it just needs this line.

Comment: make sure the production `index.html` actually includes the tag as well as development `index.html`

Comment: @FilipHalas that is it. My production index.html was rendering my actual index.html in an iframe. And the production's index.html didn't have the meta tag. Adding it there fixed it.

Comment: I've been doing web for quite a few years now and always did this automatically, today I forgot to put the tag and couldn't figure out why my web wasn't showing the responsive queries for que screen size, and 1 quick search I got my answer here, hahaha feel so dumb this happened.

Comment: i have add this line but mobile view are no responsive

Comment: I have the same issue, works on desktop but not on my mobile device and I have the meta tag as it should be and my media queries in my css. Still cant seem to find a reason for it not to work on the production webpage

Answer (score 7):

I have also faced this problem. Finally I got a solution.
Use this bellow code. Hope: problem will be solve.

`<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">`

Answer (score 5):

Though it is answered above and it is right to use

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

but if you are using React and webpack then don't forget to close the element tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

Answer (score 2):

**Responsive meta tag**

To ensure proper rendering and touch zooming for all devices, add the responsive viewport meta tag to your `<head>`.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
```