# css responsive design in mobile is not working

Tags: css, mobile

I create a html file to be responsive in any device. 
in pc when i resize the browser is fully responsiv. but when i test in mobile it is not.
here is the link.
http://cutetheme.net/resp/
thank you

Comment: Just a tip, as you get into smaller widths, it can be a good idea to switch to a fluid layout to make best use of the available space.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Responsive web design is working on desktop but not on mobile device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14304494/responsive-web-design-is-working-on-desktop-but-not-on-mobile-device)

Answer (score 13):

Add this in your head tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: thats the perfect and simple working solution. Please mark it as accepted as it may help others.