# Responsive web design works on desktop but not on mobile device

Tags: android, responsive-design, desktop

I have created a responsive web site using my desktop and it works beautifully in all modes on my desktop. When I adjust browser windows it works perfectly for the mobile phone version. However, when I check it on my mobile device - Samsung Galaxy S3 - it is not displaying.

You can view web page here: http://www.fogell.com/LayerSlider/examples/index.html

Any suggestions?

Comment: How do you decide what layout to display? Screen width? The Galaxy S3 has a 720x1280 screen. Doesn't your code interpret it as a desktop size display?

Answer (score 0):

Probably same problem/answer as [Responsive web design is working on desktop but not on mobile device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14304494/responsive-web-design-is-working-on-desktop-but-not-on-mobile-device)

You are probably missing the viewport tag