# Responsive mobile website

Tags: responsive

I have problem with my website[enter link description here](http://manley.pl)

I don't why does't work on your phone responsive menu.
In browser ewerything works ok. 
In what could be the problem?

Comment: your question may be duplicate and answer on [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14304494/responsive-web-design-is-working-on-desktop-but-not-on-mobile-device)

Comment: Thank you, the problem was in the metadata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

This is a solution to the problem with responsive.

Answer (score 3):

May try this

```
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"  content="IE=edge,chrome=1"><meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true">
```

Comment: good answer, maybe provide some context to what this is doing , so someone who doesn't know what this does can understand better