# Responsive Web not work on Mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, media-queries, responsive

I am using Chrome and I can just pull the edge of window to reduce the width.
It is working fine with media query width

but if I use my mobile or chrome F12 view as mobile function
It only zoom out the whole view port and does not have media query applied.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you show us your problem with some code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Responsive web design is working on desktop but not on mobile device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14304494/responsive-web-design-is-working-on-desktop-but-not-on-mobile-device)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure `Viewport` meta tag is set

```
<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

For more info http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp