# <meta name="viewport"> tag not working on mobile devices

Tags: bootstrap-4

Bootstrap works fine in desktop browsers, however not so well on mobile devices.

I have used the tag below, but it does not appear to make a difference, wondering if maybe something could be conflicting with it but not sure where that would originate from.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1;"/>
```

Comment: What do you expect it to do?

Comment: On posts like the one below it enables bootstrap to work properly with mobile browsers.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14304494/responsive-web-design-is-working-on-desktop-but-not-on-mobile-device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because your site is using frames, and the viewport meta tag is in the head tag of a document inside a frame.

It has to be in the head tag of the same document which contains the frameset tag.

Check [this link](https://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970917/present/frames.html) for more information about frames.