# PHP + CSS: menu layout breaks on small screens when header file is included

Tags: php, css

it's been some time since I did some coding so I'm basically a newbie in updated PHP (so please bear with me).
I've created a basic draft related to new web I'm working on. I decided to include header.php file (as it's supposed be used on many other pages on that web and I don't want to code header info manually for each page).

index.php file is located in main folder, css, js and images each in a separate folder: [web-folders-structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsP1m.jpg) .

All seems to be working fine, but when I simulate either iPad or iPhone display - menu is not resized for those type of screens (even though css styles contain detailed specs for each case).

What it should look like:
[expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/105Ri.jpg)

How it looks when header.php is included:
[distorted navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPMcH.jpg)

index1.php start of the code:

```
<?php include ("./inc/header.php"); ?>
<div id="wrap">
</div>
<!-- navigation -->
```

content of header.php file (located in "inc" folder):

```
<?php
//db start
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "pokus",)
or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');
//Set DB connection charset to utf-8
$db->set_charset("utf8");
?>
```

```
<head>
<title> EGYPTICA - svet starovekeho Egypta 2019 </title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="sk">   
<meta name="description"  content="historia starovekeho Egypta"> 
<meta name="keywords" content="Egypt, staroveky Egypt, stary Egypt, Egyptica, egyptica, egyptologia, knihy, starovek, mumia, faraon, pyramidy">  
<meta name="copyright" content="Copyright  (c) 2019 Jana Rusnakova"> 
<meta name="author" content="Jana Rusnakova">
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/menumaker.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/main-styles.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
```

I tried to remove include and insert meta tags directly into index1.php and that works fine on all type of displays. However once I use include (of header) - when I check small screens (tablet, mobile phone) it doesn't work properly.

Any advise as to what could cause this?

Thx

Comment: Have you tried adding viewport meta tag? `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Comment: @RameshNavi Yup, that was it. I had it there when all codes were located in one file.. I guess I forgot to move this key line into header file. Thank you very much ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Responsive web design is working on desktop but not on mobile device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14304494/responsive-web-design-is-working-on-desktop-but-not-on-mobile-device)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding viewport meta tag.

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` .

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a problem with the inclusion of the header.php file. I would guess that the problem is with the media queries in your CSS file since the hamburger menu is not displayed and the menu items are not hidden...