# Can't see the edits made in mobile view in chrome inspect

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, responsive-design, web-testing

I am learning web development and i think it's really cool. I am having problem in viewing my website in mobile view using chrome inspect tool. I am making the website mobile responsive but I can't see the edits made for mobile in mobile view using inspect tool. The mobile view of inspect tool just minimizes the desktop view. I actually have to minimize the browser window to see the edits that I made. I also tried it in Firefox browser but it didn't work. Anyone has solution to this?? Screenshots below.

Actual Website on Desktop View

[image: Website on Desktop view]

Website View on Chrome Inspect tool. Mobile View on inspect tool is just minimized desktop view

[image]

Website when window is minimized. It works fine here but not on inspect tool

[image]

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14304494/responsive-web-design-is-working-on-desktop-but-not-on-mobile-device

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14304494/responsive-web-design-is-working-on-desktop-but-not-on-mobile-device

Comment: Thanks, it worked :). I actually didn't knew about it.